# Exist any solution for realize upload through plupload to S3 with thumbs and function progress bar?

Tags: upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, progress-bar, plupload

I am spending already second day of searching any solution, how to do an upload of files to Amazon-S3 service with the progress bar. The uploaded image contains also thumbs. I use for it HTML5 and flash.

My problem is, that I see in the progress bar always just 0% and 100% - nothing between.

Lot of people recommended me a PLUPLOAD tool for a realization, but this doesn't works me unfortunately.

Could anyone give me a tip how to implement? I can't somewhere find any useful tutorial or example of this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fancy Upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/), here is a discussion of lad who did it using ruby-on-rails:

http://www.railstoolkit.com/posts/fancyupload-amazon-s3-uploader-with-paperclip

Fancy upload gives some time out information with large files.  You have to cath the time out and deal with it, the file will still hit the server ok.  However, this has led me to use Plupload.

Or what about this:

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=133